# Asp.net core I could add pictures, but I couldn't delete the image

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core-mvc, image-uploading

I'm using Asp.Net MVC Core. I could add pictures, but I couldn't delete the image. I could not use the following methods: Server, MapPath.

Entity add and Image upload:(successful method.I just shared with you about how I added it.)

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormFile image,Programci programci)
    {
        if (image==null || image.Length==0)
        {
            return Content("not image selected");
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/image/Programcilar", image.FileName);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await image.CopyToAsync(stream);

        }

        programci.ImageUrl = "/image/Programcilar/"+ image.FileName;
        _programciService.Add(programci);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Delete Method:(Problem.I couldn't delete the image.)

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var bulunanProgramci = _programciService.Get(id);


        _programciService.Delete(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more code for `_programciService.Delete(id);` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code and the images you should have something like this in the code that is inside `_programciService.Delete(id);` method call

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\image\\Programcilar", "controlller.jpg");

if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
}
```

Just replace static image file name `"controlller.jpg"` with the variable name of the image you are trying to delete.

Be careful with the path of the image. It should be the full path from the root drive. For example `C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\image\\Programcilar\\controlller.jpg`.

Comment: if (System.IO.File.Exists(_env.WebRootPath+bulunanProgramci.ImageUrl))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(_env.WebRootPath + bulunanProgramci.ImageUrl);
            }
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use an environmental variable to store/retrieve the path where you have stored your image.

```
string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images");
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), uploadsFolder, picName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
```

Don't forget to use:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
```

and to instatiate it in the constructor of your class:

```
public yourClass(yourContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _context = context;
        webHostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }
```